# Get indices in pandas dataframe selecting by specific column values

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, indexing

I have a pandas dataframe, which looks like this

```
   ievt ch  n_max   t0
0   0   0   0.0 0.0
1   0   1   0.0 0.0
2   0   2   6.0 175.0
3   0   3   1.0 1253.0
4   0   4   0.0 0.0
... ... ... ... ...
999995  30302   29  0.0 0.0
999996  30302   30  0.0 NaN
999997  30302   31  0.0 NaN
999998  30302   32  0.0 0.0
999999  30303   0   0.0 0.0
1000000 rows × 4 columns
```

and an array of values for the column `ievt` which looks like this

```
ievt_nbrs = array([0,    3,     7,     9, ..., 30292, 30293, 30299])
```

Now I want to get the indices of my dataframe which have these `ievt` numbers. For example for ievt number 0, I will get 33 indices (because I have 33 channels), so my indices array will start with `0,1,2,...,33, 33*3, 33*3+1,...` I hope it's clear what I'm aiming for.
What I'm doing currently to get the indices is a for loop, but that's of course very slow:

```
indices_accept = np.array([])
for i in ievt_nbrs:
    indices_accept = np.append(indices_accept, df.index[df['ievt']==i])
indices_accept = indices_accept.astype('int')
```

How can I do this using pandas indexing or something else which will be faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html?highlight=isin#pandas.Series.isin) method of your `df["ievt"]` serie:

```py
df.loc[df["ievt"].isin(ievt_nbrs), :]
```

and if you only need the index, simply call the `index` method on the resulting dataframe.

Example:

```py
>>> df 
    ievt  ch
0      0   1
1      0   2
2      0   3
3      0   4
4      0   5
5      1   1
6      1   2
7      1   3
8      1   4
9      1   5
10     2   1
11     2   2
12     2   3
13     2   4
14     2   5
>>> indices = [1, 2]
>>> df.loc[df["ievt"].isin(indices), :]
   ievt  ch
5      1   1
6      1   2
7      1   3
8      1   4
9      1   5
10     2   1
11     2   2
12     2   3
13     2   4
14     2   5
>>> df.loc[df["ievt"].isin(indices), :].index
Int64Index([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], dtype='int64')
```